# require.js + cldrjs Why renaming a config paths entry break it?

Tags: requirejs, cldr

### Summary

The rename below (s/cldr/cldrjs) breaks load functionality.

`require.config({
    paths: {
-       cldr: "./bower_components/cldrjs/dist/cldr"
+       cldrjs: "./bower_components/cldrjs/dist/cldr"
    }
 });`

require([
-   "cldr",
-   "cldr/supplemental"
+   "cldrjs",
+   "cldrjs/supplemental"
 ], function( Cldr ) {
    console.log( "Cldr instance", new Cldr( "en" ) );
 }, function() {

### Setup

Install libraries.

`bower install cldrjs requirejs`

You should get:

`cldrjs /tmp/cldrjs
├── cldrjs#0.3.2 extraneous
└── requirejs#2.1.11 extraneous`

### Usage

Open `index.html` (available at https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/10194312). Require.js should load Cldr, and your console should log an instance of it, eg:

`Cldr instance Object { attributes={...}, locale="en", supplemental=function(), more...}`

### Question

**Why does the rename break it?**

To make it easier for you, I've placed both main files (available at https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/10194312). Simply change the reference to test it.

`--- a/index.html
+++ b/index.html
@@ -4,7 +4,7 @@
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 </head>
 <body>
-    <script data-main="main.cldr.js" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
+    <script data-main="main.cldrjs.js" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>`

</body>
 </html>

### Apendix

Piece of info worth knowing...

Header of cldr.js: (available at https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/10194312)

`define(function() {
   // implementation... Yeap, no dependencies.
})`

Header of cldr/supplemental.js: (available at https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/10194312)

`define(["../cldr"], function() {
   // implementation... Dependency is the above cldr.js file.
})`

Comment: Wondering if @jrburke +jrburke could guide me what could be wrong... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/1084#issuecomment-40112805

I have chatted with @jrburke on IRC and he pointed out that

> `../cldr’ is resolved relative to ‘supplemental’ as an ID first, which ends up with a ‘cldr’ in the ID, then that is converted to a path
>   but since that path already was used for a module called ‘cldrjs’ that is a problem, does not find a ‘cldr’ module in it
>    more in a bit after i set up the project
>   but i think the end result is that you will want to use either a map or packages config

Solution:

> the general rule of thumb is: if the package only contains one JS module then paths config is good enough. If it contains multiple modules (as in this case) package config is usually a better fit
>   unless the package manager knows about front end modules

Thanks @jrburke